# VBA Error code "Run Time Error 16, Too Complex"

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic-arrays

When running a Dynamic array that is populated I am trying to get the contents of an element and receive the following error `Run-Time Error '16': Expression too complex.` The expression that is to complex?

Impactdays is a long, I populated the spreadsheet by simply stuffing the range into the array

```
ReportArray = Impact_Chart.Range("Data.EventNumber").CurrentRegion.Value

For i = LBound(ReportArray) + 1 To UBound(ReportArray)

If ReportArray(i, iImpactCol) > 0 Then
        iImpactDays = ReportArray(i, iImpactCol)<-- Tosses error here

        'more stuff
```

any ideas oh gurus of everything? :)
Oh this is 2007

Comment: Does it throw the error the _first_ time it gets to that line, or after several successful calls? If it's the latter, it's probably some sort of internal stack overflow.

Comment: Actually it appears to be attempting to evaluate a 0 (zero) in the field.  It is going past the <code> If Reportarray(i, iImpactCol) > 0 </code> call for some reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you are not using something like

```
   If (Not MyArray) = -1
```

somewhere in your program. [It has been reported](http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/showthread.php?t=191412) a connection between that and your error.

HTH!

Comment: I was using this to check is my arrays are dimensioned                  arrayTester = (Not TargetArray) = True
    
    If (Not arrayTester) Then
        IsArrayDimensioned = True
    End If

Comment: which I guess I will need to take out and do something else.

Comment: @CAB Use a variable as a flag, and test it. See the external linked thread.

Comment: @CAB please return here afterward to confirm if that worked. Your input will help others!

Comment: <sigh>  Yes blocking that code snippet out completely resolved my problem.  I will just have to go swipe some other code to check if my array is dimensioned.

Answer (score 0):

I did remove the offending stack pointer and used the following to check instead

```
Function IsArrayDimensioned(TargetArray() As Variant) As Boolean
Dim s As Integer
On Error Resume Next
s = UBound(TargetArray, 1)
If Err.Number = 0 Then
    IsArrayDimensioned = True
Else
    IsArrayDimensioned = False
End If
End Function
```

Works as advertised