# Excel Run-time error 16 expression too complex

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have this basic code in an Excel sheet

```
For x = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GRP0").Range("D9:D112").Rows.Count
' do work here
Next x
```

though when I execute it gives the error

```
Run-time error '16':

Expression too complex
```

I'm using Excel 2007 in compatibility mode, the sheet, I believe was made for/in Excel 2003, if that helps. Any ideas as to what is causing the error?

Comment: Have you tried splitting the long operation into single assignments per statement/line, so you can isolate which causes the error? (I wanted to add a comment but my rep doesn't allow me to :p, so I'm writing it as a new answer.)

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code, works fine. Are you testing it with code within the for loop? Remove it and then try to retest.

Comment: Googling this results in a number of similar issues for xl07 such [as this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838000/vba-error-code-run-time-error-16-too-complex)

Comment: Is the loop executing once or a few times or does it fail on the first iteration? Similar to Philip's question, is your loop code modifying the range it's working in? For example doing a merge cell? Lastly, if you are going to hard code that range, why not just feed it the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me just answer this question and let it leave 'unanswered' section... and for others who would look for the answer and see perfectly written question.

Problem described happens from time to time. I don't know exact reason but there is one simple way to solve it. You just need to use variable, set its value before loop starts and use this variable in loop starting line. This could be as follow:

```
Dim rowsCount As Long
    rowsCount = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GRP0").Range("D9:D112").Rows.Count
    'and any other complex statement could be placed here
For x = 1 To rowsCount
    'do work here
Next x
```

According to my experience all 'expression too complex' problems could be solved that way.

Comment: Please correct  your spelling on `rowsCount` , the reason behind is the default type of X is Int, where Int's limit is 32767. According to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164754(v=office.10).aspx) and from Excel 2007onward, the row limit is >> 32767, so it overflows.

Comment: I don't think that X as Integer is the reason of the problem. It should return 'overflow' error but there is 'expression to complex' message....

Comment: you are correct, If I declare X as Integer and hardcode 100,000 , it throws "Overflow" error.  And I am not able to reproduce the Error `expression too complex` in my 2007 Environment..