# Expression too complex error

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I know this question gets asked quite a bit, but I haven't seen an answer that I can apply to my issue. It seems that this error can be caused by quite a few things.

First of all, here is the code:

```
SurfArea = 19.63495408
Volume = 12.2718463
DeSimpleFinal = 0.009336098
Counter = 13 
pi = 4*atn(1)
tracker = 0
stepamount = (Range("A" & Counter + 1).Value) / 1000
If Range("XFD1048508").Value = 1 Then
    For x = 0 To Range("A" & Counter + 1).Value Step Stepamount
        tracker = tracker + 1
        ActiveSheet.Range("XEY" & tracker).Value = ((2 * SurfArea) / Volume) * Sqr((DeSimpleFinal * x) / pi)
        ActiveSheet.Range("XEX" & tracker).Value = x
    Next
Else
End If
```

I've decided to leave (Range("A" & Counter + 1).Value) on, because I think it might be relevant to why the code is breaking down. That cell is A14 and has the value 11 inside of it.

The line that gets flagged when I debug is the first line of the For loop. The loop doesn't even go through one iteration.

Does anybody have an idea of what it could be? I changed all my data types to variant to see if that was the issue, but that did nothing. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: I should note that the value of that range SHOULD be one, so that it does go through the loop.

Comment: I don't get any errors when I run your code.  What's the error message you're getting?

Comment: I get a Run Time Error '16': Expression too complex.

Comment: Is the value of XFD1048508 set to one, so that it goes through that For loop?

Comment: You need to remove `Range("A" & Counter + 1).Value` from the For line: Assign it to a variable and then use the variable as the limit on the For.

Comment: @TheTreeMan Yes...well technically speaking, I just took that check out.  I went through the loop no problem.  Is that all of your code?  Perhaps posting the entire Sub will give more insight (that is, if chuff's suggestion doesn't solve it for you).

Comment: I actually just did chuff's advice, which got it working... I'm not sure why that made it work though, and I'd really like to.

Comment: It's weird. I have one version of the code where I dim x as a double, and it bombs, another where x is dimmed as a variant and it runs. The typename of the variant x after assignment is double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know anywhere enough about VBA's internals to understand why, but I do know that simplifying the expression that sets the limit on a `FOR` loop will eliminate the `Error 16 - Expression Too Complex` problem. (The response to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551986/excel-run-time-error-16-expression-too-complex) as well as discussion elsewhere on the web comes to pretty much the same conclusion.)

Just declare a new variable, say, `StopAmount`, assign to it the expression you used in the `FOR` condition, and then replace the expression in the `FOR` with the name of the new variable. You get something like:

```
  StopAmount = Range("A" & Counter + 1).Value
  ......
  For x = 0 To StopAmount Step Stepamount
  ......
```

That said, there are certainly some oddities here.

For example, your original `FOR` condition worked fine if the iterator variable `x` is declared as a Variant, either implicitly or explicitly. (I declared all the variables for my tests.)

However, if `x` is dimensioned as a Double, the error returned. This is despite the fact that `TypeName(x)` showed the Variant `x` as a Double after the Range(..).Value assignment is made.

`For x = 0 To Range("A14").Value Step Stepamount` also ran with no problem.

And `For x = 0 To Cells(Counter + 1, 1).Value Step Stepamount` worked, too.

Comment: Thank you for an amazing answer. The Double thing is the most confusing part of this for me. I guess we just have to admit that VBA works in mysterious ways and move on. :P